# What is the reason for the differences in how this string is split?

Tags: python, string, methods

I am using the `str.split()` method and I can pin down what causes the difference in result, but I don't understand why it is.

```
>>> dummy_line = "Line1 \nLine2 \nLine3"
>>> print(dummy_line.split())
['Line1', 'Line2', 'Line3']

>>> print(str.split(" "))
['Line1', '\nLine2', '\nLine3']
```

Why does defining the split delimeter as `" "` in the second instance result in the returned lines including the new line escape character `\n`?

Comment: `.split` with no argument splits on *whitespace*, whereas in your second example, you are splitting only on *single spaces*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: that reads a lot more like an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.split(" ")` separates on a single space. Newlines therefore are kept.

`str.split()` breaks all whitespace. (`\s`, `\r`, `\n`, `\t`)

Maybe your misunderstanding is Python's support for default function arguments?

Hint: Try `dummy_line = "Line 1\nLine 2"`

Comment: More specifically, `str.split(' ')` separates on a single space only, whereas `str.split()` separates on 1 or more spaces.

Comment: I wouldn't call a newline character or carriage return "one or more spaces"

Comment: (1 or more spaces OR a newline character, but I was focusing on the part of the answer that's imprecise).  This is not true: "str.split(" ") separates on spaces only."  It separates on *one* space only, not *spaces*.

Comment: And if we want to be really specific, here's straight from the `str.split` docstring: "If sep is not specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator".  A newline is considered a whitespace character.

Comment: @cricket_007 What does escape sequence `\s` denote? I've attempted to use it in Python but it doesn't do much of anything..

Comment: @seeker It's a regular expression for a single space. You have to use `import re; re.split('\s', 'some string')` for it to work

Answer (score 0):

- split() - strip all the white space characters for you - off course including the '\n'
- split(" ") - strip exactly one white space for you.